# How to replace a single or more space before .mp3 file extension in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

!As you can see in this image when i want to try to remove a single space before.mp3 it remoes space with "." But i want to remove only space

For example:

[image]

```
My regex:\s+\.
Txt:Badri Ki Dulhania Title Track (Neha Kakkar) 190Kbps .mp3
Output:Badri Ki Dulhania Title Track (Neha Kakkar) 190Kbps.mp3
```

So how i doing thsi![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a positive lookahead to surgically remove only the whitespace.  From regex mode:

**Find:**

```
\s+(?=\.)
```

**Replace:**

```
(nothing)
```